# How to query the most recent row for each value in column X?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to query the most recent row for each value in a column X.

My current attempt is:

```
SELECT max(mytimestamp), mytable.* FROM mytable GROUP BY X
```

but while the first column in the result contains the latest timestamp, the other columns are not from the most recent row.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT M.*
from
(
 SELECT X, max(mytimestamp) MaxT
 FROM mytable
 GROUP BY X
) N
inner join mytable M on M.X = N.X and M.mytimestamp = N.MaxT
```

While MySQL allows you to mix aggregate and non-aggregate columns in a GROUP BY query.. please don't.  Consider the scenario similar to what you have:

```
 SELECT max(mytimestamp) MaxT, min(mytimestamp) MinT, mytable.*
 FROM mytable
 GROUP BY X
```

Think about it and let me know which record the columns should come from (hint: max or min).

Answer (score 0):

This only involves one table? Then why not this:

```
select * from mytable order by mytimestamp desc limit 1
```

Comment: because I need a result for every different value in column X

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need the group by:

SELECT max(timestamp), mytable.* FROM mytable limt 1;

Comment: I need a result for every different value in column X

Comment: Right - you never said that in your question! Or at least not clearly. Sample output and sample data would be helpful